# Message key as Long in Kafka Streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to use Long as type of the message key, but I get

```
Exception in thread "kafka_stream_app-f236aaca-3f90-469d-9d32-20ff694806ff-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Failed to deserialize key for record. topic=test, partition=0, offset=0
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNodeRecordDeserializer.deserialize(SourceNodeRecordDeserializer.java:38)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:84)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:117)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:474)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addRecordsToTasks(StreamThread.java:642)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:548)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:519)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Size of data received by LongDeserializer is not 8
```

I checked and the `data.length` is `7`.

In streamsConfiguration I've set

```
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.Long().getClass().getName());
```

and I use

```
KStream<Long, GenericRecord> stream = builder.stream(topic);
```

I've tried sending the message via a simple app and also with `kafka-avro-console-producer`:

```
/opt/confluent-3.3.0/bin/kafka-avro-console-producer \
--broker-list localhost:9092 \
--topic test \
--property key.separator=, \
--property parse.key=true \
--property key.schema='{"type":"long"}' \
--property value.schema='{"type":"string"}' \
--property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
```

with message

```
123,"293"
```

Using the `kafka-avro-console-consumer` I can consume the message and see (with `--property print.key=true` that the key sent is correctly `123`)

Any idea what could be wrong when decoding the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `kafka-avro-console-producer` the key is not serialized as plain `Long` but as an Avro type. Thus, you need to use a corresponding Avro Serde with the same schema you used on the write path (ie, `'{"type":"long"}"`).

Also, your return type will not be `Long` but an Avro type.